# Preventing Stackoverflow exception using static methods

Tags: c#, stack-overflow

I was programming a class which recursively instantiates itself in order to parse a XSD into another type of XSD. It downloads it from internet and walks through each element and if one of the elements has a `complexType` which is located in another `URI` then it simply does the same thing by creating one of the instance of itself.

But when the XSD is so big and has many external links, today my class crashed because of the `Stackoverflow` exception.

I decided to put some of the instance methods to another class (`Helper.cs`) as static members and now call them from within the parser class.

But I wonder if this is a good solution and can solve the `Stackoverflow` exception? I know how the instance methods are put into the stack frames but Will the static methods be treated in the same way? Will it cause any `Stackoverflow` exception?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only difference between instance methods and static methods is that instance methods take an additional hidden `this` parameter.  (actually, instance methods can also be `virtual`, but that doesn't make any difference here)

They are both equally vulnerable to stack overflow.

If you want to avoid stack overflows for large inputs, don't use recursion.

Comment: +1. Recursive code to parse untrusted input is security issue. There is not much to do but refactor to avoid recursion OR have some sort of "deep recursion prevention" counter to fail for excessively nested structures.

Answer (score 1):

Static vs instance has no bearing on the question. the stack depth rises and falls based on calls, not on actual memory containing a function be it on the stack or the heap.

look for any recursion without a solid exit condition, loops that count to infinity, or datasources that are just plain too big. is your project running on a webserver? IIS has a builtin limit on stack size (compiled into w3wp.exe) that is more restrictive than desktop apps.